# Spring, JPA transactions works only in JUnit test but not in application

Tags: spring, web-applications, transactions, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a little problem with transactions. I use Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, Spring Data 1.0.3.RELEASE JPA with Hibernate provider. When I start a junit test where is a method annotated with `@Transactional` it seems fine but when I start a whole application there are no errors but transactions don't work.
Here's my configurations and sample code:

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sheedo.upload" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.sheedo.upload.repository" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:messages/*.properties</value>
                <value>classpath*:*.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

UserRepository.java

> public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{ }

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(String name, String surname) {
        User u = new User(name, surname);
        userRepository.save(u);
        throw new RuntimeException(); // to invoke a rollback
    }
}
```

UserServiceTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml" })
public class UserServiceTest {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void testUserAdd() {
        userService.addUser("John", "Doe");
    }

}
```

In this case of JUnit test, transaction doesn't work event though the service method is annotated with `@Transactional`. When I add this annotation to `testUserAdd()` method I get this in console:

```
2012-05-17 11:17:54,208 INFO [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener] - Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@23ae2a testClass = UserRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.sheedo.upload.repository.UserRepositoryTest@7f52c1, testMethod = testUserAdd@UserRepositoryTest, testException = java.lang.RuntimeException, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@111fd28 testClass = UserRepositoryTest, locations = '{classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]
```

which is correct I suppose. So, how can be possible that `@Transactional` annotation works only in Junit test class, but not in others spring beans ?

My theory is that `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` somehow provides this transaction. Have I something wrong in my spring configuration that transactions don't work in my app but only in Junit test classes? Something missing in appContext?

*Edit:*
log:

```
2012-05-17 12:46:10,770 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2012-05-17 12:46:10,770 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e4080] for JPA transaction
2012-05-17 12:46:10,979 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e4080] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@1f87491] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval
Hibernate: insert into user (name, surname) values (?, ?)
2012-05-17 12:46:11,062 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction commit
2012-05-17 12:46:11,062 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e4080]
2012-05-17 12:46:11,142 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e4080] after transaction
2012-05-17 12:46:11,142 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils] - Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Comment: How do you diagnose that transactions "don't work"?

Comment: When I debug this transactional method in UserService, it saved entity into the database after "userRepository.save(user)" even though the method finished with exception. And I have no log in console that transaction began.

Comment: Enable the "org.springframework.transaction" loggers.Post the same. This will help in further analysis.

Comment: all I got is this in startup: `2012-05-17 12:41:10,386 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] - Adding transactional method 'addUser' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''` no log when I call the method..

Comment: ok, I added `log4j.logger.org.springframework.orm.jpa=debug` and I got something when method was called. Look at my edit in main post.

Comment: You log says that a new transaction is getting created for `save` method.If I am not wrong, your log should have said `Creating new transaction with name [...UserServiceImpl.addUser]`.

Comment: yes, but what does mean this: `2012-05-17 12:46:10,979 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager] - Not exposing JPA transaction [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@e4080] as JDBC transaction because JpaDialect [org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect@1f87491] does not support JDBC Connection retrieval` ?

Comment: It committed changes, but exception was thrown. Why there isn't a rollback ?

Comment: `Not exposing JPA transaction..` should not be a problem.Describe the environment in use (server, hibernate version etc).Log before `2012-05-17 12:46:10,770` may give some more info.Try additional <tx:annotation-driven /> as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051721/declarative-transactions-transactional-doesnt-work-with-repository-in-sprin

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Adding `<tx:annotation-driven />` into servlet context helped.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. Also, read the solution of adding a `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag in my web configuration (`spring-servlet.xml`, instead of `applicationContext.xml`), and worked for me.

But I did not consider that a good solution, so I tried to understand why that was happening...

And well, it turned out that a `<context:component-scan>` tag I had in my `spring-servlet.xml` was also including the `@Service` classes in its scan (the `base-package` specification was too general). This was weird because I had an `include-filter` in place referring to the `@Controller` annotation... but anyway, it seems that the application context for the web layer was the one creating the `@Service` instances instead of the application context created for `applicationContext.xml` --which is the one defining the business layer--, and as the former didn't have transactionality enabled... I didn't have any transactions.

Solution (good one): better (more specific) `component-scan` configuration at `spring-servlet.xml`

Comment: Had the same problem. Web app context was loading wrong beans even though include filters were defined. And obviously there was no <tx:annotation-drive/> in the web app context. Inspect your logs for when the spring-servlet.xml (or whatever you named your web layer applicationcontext) loads and look for this statement in the log: "Bean factory for WebApplicationContext" - you can search through those beans to see if the web app context loaded it.